# Windows Phone 8.1 AppBarButton Template not editable

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, blend

I am not able to redefine the Template of an `AppBarButton` inside `BottomAppBar` in a Windows Phone 8.1 project.

In Visual Studio XAML designer it changes (it shows "button 2" text), but when I deploy it to the phone or to the emulator, the default template is applied.

I tried to right click the control, "Edit template", "Edit a copy...", but it's not available. Is it possible, to redefine this template?

My XAML code (just a very simplified example):

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton
                Label="button">
                <AppBarButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="button 2" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </AppBarButton.Template>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I have Windows 8.1 Pro with Visual Studio Community 2013 Update 4 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to customize the app bar on Windows Phone 8.1 beyond the foreground and background colors. On Windows Phone the app bar is system UI rather than app as UI.

If you want to customize your app bar buttons you can put them in a custom panel docked at the bottom of the page instead of in a Page.BottomAppBar

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely right click and edit a copy. I just did this recently. Try putting a temporary AppBarButton at the top of your page and right click that one. Here is the default style in case you need it:

```
            <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Width="80">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="48"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="38.5" Margin="0,12,0,4" Width="38.5">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="38.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="38.5"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="9.5" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="0,0,0,10.5" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="70.5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: This will work for an AppBarButton on the page itself but not in the page's CommandBar