# Windows Phone 8.1 BottomAppBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to show list of icons in BottomAppBar. Everything look fine in XAML Designer as below:

XAML:

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Back" 
                              Command="{Binding Back}"
                              IsCompact="False" 
                              Label="X"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" 
                              Command="{Binding Refresh}"
                              IsCompact="False" 
                              Label="X"/>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Margin="20 0 20 0">
                    <AppBarButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <StackPanel Width="65">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Cut"  Foreground="#F9F9F9"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#F9F9F9"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Width="65">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Cut"  Foreground="#F9F9F9"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#F9F9F9"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <!--Others-->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </AppBarButton.Template>
                </AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Designer:

[image]

Unfortunately when I run the code on my device Lumia 640 there are no items in . There is just blank space in the place of my icon list. Does anyone know how do I achive that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284229/how-to-add-icons-to-secondarycommands-in-command-bar

Comment: What's the os version of Lumia 640?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: I don't think you can customise the app bar to that level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328565/windows-phone-8-1-appbarbutton-template-not-editable